# Configuring wildcard pattern in upstream for tinyproxy

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

I want to use tinyproxy to redirect all the sites except abc.com to a particular
host, for which I am trying to configure wildcard entry in tinyproxy.conf but none of them is working. I tried following options

1) upstream 218.150.67.262:8080 "."
   upstream 228.150.67.262:8080 "abc.com"

2) upstream 218.150.67.262:8080 "*"
   upstream 228.150.67.262:8080 "abc.com"

3) upstream 218.150.67.262:8080 ".*"
   upstream 228.150.67.262:8080 "abc.com"

All of the above rules work for abc.com but for other sites (first rule with wildcard pattern) its not working. It will be really helpful if someone can help with the wildcard pattern that I can configure in tinyproxy.conf.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found the answer myself, basically for a wildcard we can use the following
entry in tinyproxy.conf

upstream 218.150.67.262:8080 .

Answer (score 0):

From config intructions:

```
# Syntax: upstream type (user:pass@)ip:port ("domain")

# For example:
#  # connection to test domain goes through testproxy
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 ".test.domain.invalid"
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 ".our_testbed.example.com"
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 "192.168.128.0/255.255.254.0"
#
```

I found the following to work to proxy all domains

```
upstream socks5 user:pass@domain.com:port
```

Simply exclude the quoted domain